# URL works fine from browser but from google plus we get a internal service error

Tags: google-plus, internal-server-error

The website URL works fine. The link from google maps on the phone works fine. For some reason when you google it in the browser (mobile browser or desktop) you get an Internal Service Error. Google said it was nothing on their end to be done.

Has anyone encountered this or have an idea of what's causing it? The error received is below.

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator and inform them of the time the error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache Server at www.thetechbuyer.com Port 80

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, an Internal Server Error is internal to *your* webapp or web service on *your* host. It usually means that your program, whatever it is doing, has crashed. This could be because of misconfiguration, or a bug in your code, or something else - without knowing more (possibly a lot more) about your server environment, it is impossible to know what.

Check your server logs - they should have more information.

(It also isn't clear what this has to do with Google+.)